# Apache2 virtual hosts configuration port 80 to 8888

Tags: apache, vhosts

I am struggling to configure virtual hosts on a remote server to do the following:
I have a Tomcat running on port 8888 and want to serve it to the public on port 80. To do so, I have a v-host config like so, which works just fine:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName subdomain.myserver.com
    ServerAlias some-alias.com www.some-alias.com
    Redirect permanent / http://myserver.com:8888
</VirtualHost>
```

Furthermore, I want to run some php-scripts that are located in /var/www/auth/. I have tried to add them underneath the upper v-host config, but they are just not reachable:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName subdomain.myserver.com
    ServerAlias some-alias.com www.some-alias.com
    DocumentRoot /www/auth/
    Redirect permanent /auth http://myserver.com:80/auth
</VirtualHost>
```

With best regards!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/auth/
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteRule (.*)  http://myserver.com:8888%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Or maybe you even want to make it even prettier for your users:

```
ServerName subdomain.myserver.com
ServerAlias some-alias.com www.some-alias.com myserver.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/auth/
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteRule (.*)  http://myserver.com:8888%{REQUEST_URI} [P]
</VirtualHost>
```